# merge values of unique keys of json string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

i have a json output code like this:

```
{"a":{"p1":"1"},"a":{"p2":"2"},"b":{"b1":"b2"}}
```

how to convert it to below using javascript or jquery or php ?

```
{"a":{"p1":"1","p2":"2"},"b":{"b1":"b2"}}
```

EDIT:
i generate json code by this code:

```
parts2.push('"'+$(this).attr('alt')+'":{"'+$(this).attr('title') + '"' + ":" + '"'+$(this).attr('value') + '"}' );
```

however $(this).attr('alt') maybe repeated in loop and i want to prevent duplicate key and instead append value to that key

Comment: How did you get the incorrect JSON?

Comment: Your first output is valid JSON but you won't be able to get the result you need from it using Javascript. The second `a` key overwrites the first!

Comment: i added some info thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each property of an object is supposed to have a unique key name. If you try to parse JSON with duplicate key names, only the last occurring value is used, so it isn't possible to parse this with the native `JSON.parse` and still expect data to be preserved.

As per your edit, you can prevent the duplicates from ever occurring:

```
var obj = {};

if typeof obj[$(this).attr('alt')] == "undefined"
    obj[$(this).attr('alt')] = {};

obj[$(this).attr('alt')][$(this).attr('title')] = $(this).attr('value');
parts2.push(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: Uhm, why is it **invalid**? Any reference for proving that?

Comment: @zerkms Niul seems to have found a reference, if you want to have a look. I realize it could be argued that it says `SHOULD`, and not `MUST`, so JSON with duplicate key names is valid.

Comment: your code works fine but it does not append second parameters to the occurred key

Answer (score 2):

You should merge the value before you generate the JSON string or you have to implement a JSON parser yourself to parse your JSON.

In http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627:

> The names within an object SHOULD be unique

Answer (score 1):

Instead of stringing the pseudo-JSON, just create an object, fill that, and stringify the object when you send it:

```
var parts = {};
$('.foo')each(function()
{//the loop, here parts is being filled
    parts.[$(this).attr('alt')] = parts.[$(this).attr('alt')] || {};//initialize to object if property doesn't exist
    parts.[$(this).attr('alt')] = [$(this).attr('title')] = $(this).attr('value');
});
//make JSON:
partsJSON = JSON.stringify(parts);
//{a:{p1:foo,p2:bar},b:{p3:foobar}} or something
```

Comment: @h0mayun: I don't know what you're doing with the data, nor where it comes from, it could well be that the `alt` or `title` attribute of some element contains forbidden chars (dashes are not allowed in property names, for example)... provide the full code and I'll edit my answer